# how can i write UDF to convert second column in upper case

Tags: pig-udf

```
   package com.hadoopexpert;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
   import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

   public class upper extends EvalFunc<String>
  {
   public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
   if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
       return null;
    try{
       String str = (String)input.get(0);
      return str.toUpperCase();      }catch(Exception e){
      throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);


     }    }
}
```

I want to convert the second column of below i/p file to upper case is this correct code?
   input file-
    101,ahmed
    102,kranthi
    103,sagar
    104,mamtha

Answer (score 0):

No, you indexed are wrong. `(String)input.get(0)` gets the first column. `(String)input.get(1)` will give you the second column.

By the way, you can just use Pig provided UDF call [UPPER](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/func.html#upper) to uppercase a String.